# How to use Cordova

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I'm currently trying to use Cordova to build an ios app and I've already had all the pages of my app done in separate HTML files such as "add_entry.html" and "inbox.html". But it seems like when I tried to run my program through "cordova emulate ios" in my terminal, it only runs the index.html file that was built for cordova. 
Is there a way to get it to run the other html files I made instead of index.html? 
I'm very new to using Cordova so please let me know if you're having trouble understanding my questions..
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cordova emulate ios` will emulate your **entire** website. You just have to make the index page **link** to your other pages. You specifically **need** an `index.html` file in a Cordova application, which will be the first page that you see when you load up your application.

All website need an index, and you cannot circumvent that.

Keep in mind that `ios` emulation (and build process) is only possible through XCode on an Apple Mac computer. Android emulation and development is possible on Windows (with [`cordova run android`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/)). You may be looking for [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) to help you with this.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! Now I realize how obvious the answer to this question is :(

Comment: No problem! Cordova can be rather daunting and confusing to work with at first, and it's understandable to think that it would work differently to regular web applications. This isn't the case though, so just plan to build a 'regular' website, and consider Cordova to be part of your build process :) Also, please don't forget to mark a solution as correct to remove this question from the 'Unanswered Questions' queue. Of course, in saying that, you are under no obligation to mark my answer (or any other answer) as correct, though it does help to keep things flowing smoothly :)

Answer (score 0):

looks like you try to run cordova on a normal pc with windows or linux.

you can't compile a ios app with cordova in emulator. for compiling ios apps you have to buy an apple computer. perhaps phonegap build is an option for you.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention. I'm actually using a mac with xcode to compile my ios app :)

Comment: than something else is wrong. post your code and we can help. without code nobody can tell you whats wrong